# Select the suitable figure from the four alternatives that would complete the square matrix.

Tags: puzzle

[image]

Tried to find different clues from the image such as counting sides, shapes, sizes etc. but no solid clue found.

**I think** the answer is 'D', requesting your opinions.

Comment: WHY do you think the answer is 'D'?

Comment: thinking at least single star should be present, not a proper reason though. Solved other questions but this question I am stuck.